# Amplify retain order on mutation

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify

Is there a a way to retain the order so that when update happens does n't move to end of the list.

Here in the code product update the updated item moves to end of the list.

```
this.updateProductListener = API.graphql(
        graphqlOperation(onUpdateProducts)
    ).subscribe({
        next: productData => {
            console.log(productData);
            const newProduct = productData.value.data.onUpdateProducts;

            const prevProducts = this.state.products.filter(
                product => product.id !== newProduct.id
            );
            const updatedProducts = [...prevProducts, newProduct];
            this.setState({ products: updatedProducts });

            this.updateProductListener.unsubscribe()

        }

    });
```

Comment: just write better update fn? use map instead of filtering out

Comment: @xadm Thanks. how will map solve the issue?